# How to check DT has no rows selected Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

What is the default value of DT's `input$table_rows_selected` if no rows are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `input$table_rows_selected` if no rows are selected is  `NULL`

if you wanna check how many rows are selected/ or if no rows are selected you can easily use `print(input$table_rows_selected)` and in the console you gonna get the values according to the selection.

**[UPDATE]**

Check this code out:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
dataTableOutput("table"),
textOutput("text")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
   output$table <- renderDataTable({
     datatable(iris)
   })

   output$text <- renderText({
     if(length(input$table_rows_selected) > 0){
     data <-  input$table_rows_selected
     data}
     else{print("NULL")}
   })

   }
)
```

if there is no row selected it will print `NULL`, when rows are selected we get the index number of them.

Comment: When I click on my DT along with your code, I get the index however when deselected nothing is printed out? I have tried using if(is.null(input$table_rows_selected)) but that doesn't work either